# strange outputs by programs, too stupid to solve :c

Tags: java

so I have exercise from a college to finish and I believe I am close to it but yet so far. I am not asking for a specific answer, I would love to know how to "overwrite a variable?" (not sure if thats a right name for that kind of action).

Here is the question : http://pastebin.com/riDYS39D

The problem which I have is that, I don't know exactly how to overwrite data in variable which was created in if statement.

and the code, any help is always welcome

```
import java.util.Scanner;



public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    double grossPaid, allowance1, allowance2, totalTaxPaid, netPay, grossAfterAllowance;
    double taxSaved;
    final double GROSSRATIO;
    String idNumber, name, address, strln;
    char maritalStatus;
    allowance1 = 25000;
    allowance2 = 20000;
    GROSSRATIO = 500000;

    taxSaved = 0.00;




    /* trash
    grossAfterAllowance = grossPaid - allowanceGiven;
    totalTaxPaid = grossAfterAllowance - netPay;
    */


    System.out.println("Enter your employee identification number: ");
    idNumber = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your address: ");
    address = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter your marital status: ");
    strln = input.next();
    maritalStatus = strln.charAt(0);
        if (maritalStatus == 'S')                                                                                                          
            taxSaved = 0.20;

        if (maritalStatus == 'M')
            taxSaved = 0.23;





    System.out.println("Enter your gross payment: ");
    grossPaid = input.nextDouble();
       if (grossPaid < GROSSRATIO)
        netPay = (grossPaid - allowance1) * taxSaved;

         if (grossPaid >= GROSSRATIO)
        netPay = (grossPaid - allowance2) * taxSaved;




    System.out.println(maritalStatus);
    netPay = (grossPaid * maritalStatus);
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("ID: " + idNumber);
    System.out.println("Address: " + address);
    System.out.println("Marital Status: " + strln);
    System.out.println("Gross Payment: " + grossPaid);
    System.out.println("Net pay: " + netPay);



    }
```

}

Comment: is the variable taxSaved?

Comment: umm.. but taxSaved isn't created in if statement?

Comment: @eis I want data to be moved from if statement to the top, thats it

Comment: I wonder what does that even mean

Comment: @eis "Created" is a misnomer. The variable is *declared* in the line `double taxSaved;`, and it is *initially assigned* in the `if` statement. Since it logically doesn't exist in between, it's a matter of opinion where it is "created", if at all. --- So, for OP: Objects are created, variables are not, they are declared and assigned.

Comment: also, the title of the question talks about "strange outputs". what is the strange output?

Comment: Your question "how to overwrite data in variable" is confusing, since you assign the value `0.00` to `taxSaved`, then *overwrite* that in the `if` statement, so you already know how.

Comment: @eis "strange outputs" is caused by `netPay = (grossPaid * maritalStatus)`, since `maritalStatus` is a `char`. Enhanced my answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your first input variable `idNumber`, this is how you overwrite a variable:

```
String idNumber = "";
System.out.println("Enter your employee identification number: ");
idNumber = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("ID Number: " + idNumber);

System.out.println("Enter your updated employee identification number: ");
idNumber = input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Updated ID Number: " + idNumber);
```

Comment: you didn't read my question, " I don't know exactly how to overwrite data in variable which was created in if statement." i.e taxSaved

Comment: Umm...it wasnot created in `if` statement. It was assigned a value, and I guess you can still overwrite it with any value you want to, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

*You said "any help is always welcome" so here is my analysis of your code.*

It is general practice to declare your variables as close to their usage as possible, most often that means when first assigned, e.g.:

```
String address = input.nextLine();
```

Marital status is supposed to be lowercase `'s'` or `'m'`. You should use `nextLine()` and validate it, e.g.

```
char maritalStatus;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter your marital status (s/m):");
    String line = input.nextLine();
    maritalStatus = (line.length() == 1 ? line.charAt(0) : '?');
} while (maritalStatus != 's' && maritalStatus != 'm');
```

Your `GROSSRATIO` is supposed to be `50000`, not `500000`.

You are inconsistent about use of constants.

- `GROSSRATIO` is uppercase and final. Perfect!
- `allowance1` and `allowance2` are lowercase and not final.
- `0.20` and `0.23` are not named constants.

`maritalStatus` is a `char`, so this line compiles, but is definitely not what you want, and **is the cause of your "strange outputs"**. Just remove the line:

```
netPay = (grossPaid * maritalStatus);
```

You are also printing `maritalStatus` by itself without label. Remove it.

You have two `if` statements for assigning `netPay` that are opposites, but compiler doesn't see that, so `netPay` is not definitely assigned. Just change second `if` statement to `else`.

`totalTaxPaid` and `grossAfterAllowance` are not used. Remove them.

The calculation of `netPay` actually calculates `totalTax`.

You are not printing all required output.

Comment: Okay, so I change some things, I can't use 'do, while' etc juts because we didn't have lecture on it yet :v, it seems working right now http://pastebin.com/RvHDsX28 thank you !